# Android generate PDF using template

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation

I would like to generate a PDF usgin data from my databse to a preset PDF template.  The question will be, do you think or is it possible to send data or generate this pdf to a template using Android or do you think it is best to send the data to a server and have the server generate the PDF instead?

I know that Android can generate a PDF, but the bigger question will be can it insert data into a layout template and then generate it?

Comment: where's the data? Originating from the server or only on the Android? And where is the PDf needed? Only on the Android or do you wish it to be server-side for other processing or storage. i think you need to provide all the scenarios before an answer can be provided. certainly there are products to do either one (render server-side or render client-side). And certainly client-side has more limitations, especially if the PDF is needed server side for something else. But if you wish to render without a wire (no connection), then client side is the only way.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for the extra questions that I have not thought to provide to you.  Actually what is happening is that the data is collected on the phone/app and must be consolidated into a pdf. That data is written to spots in a pdf template and then sent out via email.

Comment: What I decided to do, mostly because of multiple templates and because of the User's data plan, is to send the data to a remote server which will build the pdf itself and then email it out itself.  That way the only data transmission on the user phone is the text transmission of the data itself.  Should result in an app that is faster and costs less for the user.